# How can I group by id and sort and numerate for days?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

everyone!

I am a pandas learner and I have no idea how can I solve it! Please, help me!

I have a table like this:

```
id       sales_day        number of purchases    
1        Monday           100
2        Monday           110
3        Monday           120
1        Tuesday          130
1        Wednesday        140
2        Tuesday          150
2        Wednesday        160
2        Friday           170
3        Tuesday          180
```

The expect result is as follows:

And I want to sort by column 'number of purchases'. How can I use python solve the problem?

```
id       sales_day        number of purchases    rang
1        Monday           100                    1
1        Tuesday          130                    2
1        Wednesday        140                    3
2        Monday           110                    1
2        Tuesday          150                    2
2        Wednesday        160                    3
2        Friday           170                    4
3        Monday           120                    1
3        Tuesday          180                    2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)** to get `rang` column and use **[`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)** to get sorted values:

```
df["rang"] = df.groupby("id")["sales_day"].cumcount() + 1
df = df.sort_values(["id","number of purchases"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've done it!